# Multi columns listbox with checkboxes and images

Tags: vb6

I'm searching a listbox able to display images, checkboxes and allowing a multi-column display.
When I write about multi-column displaying, I mean a display of a dataset on several columns with an horizontal scrollbar (like a Listbox with the property Columns > 0).

If I'm not wrong, this Listbox can't display images.
I tried to use a Listview, but I can't use multi-column display.

Do you know how I could solve my problem, please?

Comment: there were many custom controls for VB6 which would act as a drop down grid.  I am not sure how many are still available though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MSFlexGrid` check the [example](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_checkgrid.html)